# Simple Program: I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 105 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android

I am beginner and I made a simple app to draw champions from the crystals (based on Marvel COC game theme :-)). I has two activity classes i.e. DrawActivity Class, has 3 buttons to Draw 1 or 5 or 10 Hero Crystals based on Random nos generated in Champ Activity. In the logcat i can see I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 105 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I read other posts, but cannot understand anything what I need to do to resolve it. Appreciate your help here.

Edit - I click the buttons and click back to come to drawActivity. Repeat it multiple times, thats when i get this intermittently.

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mChampsList;
    private Button mDraw01Button;
    private Button mDraw05Button;
    private Button mDraw10Button;
    private int noOfChamps;

    public static final String TAG ="DrawChamps";
    public static final String KEY_NUMOFCHAMPS ="DrawChamps_NoOfChamps";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

        mChampsList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.champs_list);

       // Log.d(TAG, ChampsActivity.getChampList());
        mChampsList.setText(ChampsActivity.getChampList());

        mDraw01Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.draw1_button);
        mDraw05Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.draw5_button);
        mDraw10Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.draw10_button);

        mDraw01Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noOfChamps = 1;
                startChampActivity();
            }
        });

        mDraw05Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noOfChamps = 5;
                startChampActivity();
            }
        });

        mDraw10Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noOfChamps = 10;
                startChampActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(KEY_NUMOFCHAMPS, noOfChamps);
    }

    public void startChampActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(DrawActivity.this,ChampsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ChampsActivity.EXTRA_NUMOFCHAMPS,noOfChamps);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Champ Activity - Draws the champs based on random no. and display it

```
public class ChampsActivity extends Activity {

    private final static double fourStarHero = 0.04;
    private final static double threeStarHero = 0.2;
    private static int[] champCount = {0, 0, 0};
    private static int noOfDraws=0;
    private TextView mShowResult;

    private static final String[] champsList = {"Thor", "Gamora", "Iron Fist", "Iron Man",
            "Star Lord", "Dr. Strange", "Drax", "Juggernaut", "Storm", "Wolverine", "Hulk",
            "Magneto", "Ultron", "Daredevil", "Capt. America", "Rocket Racoon","Magic","Black Panther"};

    public static final String EXTRA_NUMOFCHAMPS = "ChampsAct_NoOfChamps";
    public static final String TAG ="ChampsAct";

    private static StringBuilder drawResultSet = new StringBuilder();

    public static String getChampList() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < champsList.length; i++) {
            result.append(champsList[i].toUpperCase()).append(", ");
        }
        return result.toString();

    }

    private static String getChampName() {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * champsList.length);
        return champsList[rand].toUpperCase();
    }

    private static void getChamps(int noOfChamps) {

        drawResultSet.setLength(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfChamps; i++) {
            double rand = Math.random();

            if (rand < fourStarHero) {
                champCount[2]++;
                drawResultSet.append("4 Star ").append(ChampsActivity.getChampName()).append("\n");
            } else if (rand < threeStarHero) {
                champCount[1]++;
                drawResultSet.append("3 Star ").append(ChampsActivity.getChampName()).append("\n");
            } else {
                champCount[0]++;
                drawResultSet.append("2 Star ").append(ChampsActivity.getChampName()).append("\n");
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_champs);
        noOfDraws = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NUMOFCHAMPS,1);

        getChamps(noOfDraws);
        //Log.d(TAG, drawResultSet.toString());

        mShowResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_heroes);
        mShowResult.setText(drawResultSet.toString());



    }

}
```

Comment: When you see the message about skipped frames? When you launch your activity or press one of your buttons?

Comment: Just edited the post for the trigger. Get it on click of buttons